# Create a Multitrait-Multimethod Matrix

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a [Multitrait-Multimethod Matrix](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/mtmmmat.php) using R for validity purposes (I will also use CFA so that's not the answer to this question).  How can I use R to create an MTMM similar to this:

[image]

I've looked at the `MTMM` function in psy package.  If this is what I want it appears to be in a very unfamiliar form (not at all like the image above).  I provided some fake data to help:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 270, replace=T), 10, 27))
names(x) <- paste(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=9), rep(c(1:9), 3), sep="")
x
```

**Coding for the column names:**

- A, B, C are the 3 methods
- 1-3 are trait 1
- 4-6 are trait 2
- 7-9 are trait 3

I'm guessing this is easier than I'm making it out to be but I just couldn't find a way.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: A general logic might be to use Methods as panels, traits as categorical axis, and then color the cells in the correlation matrix according to the correlation coefficient (see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9918/1036) on the stats site for an example). It would be easier to help if you actually reproduced your correlation matrix. For the love of god please don't use that color scheme in the picture you included!

Comment: It was brought to my attention by Andy that the picture above is misleading.  I don't really want to output to be in nice graphic form, just that the output is correct numerically speaking.  It can be ugly (and is actually preferred right now).